# Swift NotificationCenter Can't unwrap Optional.None

Tags: macos, notifications, swift, center

I'm programming simple program 
i want show notification on mac os x

this is my code

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

var notification:NSUserNotification = NSUserNotification()
notification.title = "TEST"
notification.subtitle = "TTTT"


var notificationcenter:NSUserNotificationCenter = NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter()
if(notificationcenter != nil) {
    notificationcenter.scheduleNotification(notification)
}
```

that code build succeeded but when stop running code

```
fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None

var notificationcenter:NSUserNotificationCenter = NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter()
```

what can i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this because you try unwrap optional which can be nil, you can do it like that:

```
if let notificationCenter = NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter() {
    notificationcenter.scheduleNotification(notification)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a variable as explicit.

```
var notificationcenter:NSUserNotificationCenter
```

That means it **can not be nil**.

But this

```
NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter()
```

can **fail**, meaning it then **returns nil**.

---

Try this

```
var notificationcenter: NSUserNotificationCenter? = NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter()
```

Your var is then **optional**, it now **may be set to nil**.